# Storing a property which is an array of strings but options using aws amplify datastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using aws amplify datastore to connect my app to a dynamodb backend.

I have an Item type which has a property named tags, which is defined as Array of strings

```
type Item @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  tags: [String]
}
```

The tags property is not required to be present. But when i save the Item without the tag property,

```
await DataStore.save(new Item({ content: 'abc' })
```

DataStore throws this error -

```
Error: Field tags should be of type string[], object received.null
```

So i tried saving an empty array when there were no tags

```
await DataStore.save(new Item({ content: 'abc', tags: [] })
```

But then dynamodb threw this error when trying to create the item

```
{
  localModel: {
   // item content and some extra fields
   "tags": Array [],
  },
  "message": "Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 9AQ0STOFFLGPUGR1S16BTORT8VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
}
```

How do i save a property which is an array of strings but optional?

Answer (score 2):

Your *tag* property is defined as a *nullable* **List** of **String** elements `tags: [String]` which means that the list can be `null` but cannot be empty because of its type definiton. *DataStore* will warn you but DynamoDB resolver will force you.

If you are expecting to have null values or you want an empty list define your property like so

`tags: [String!]`

> This means that the list itself **can** be null, but it can’t have any null members.
>
> *valid:* `null, [], ['a', 'b']`
>
> *invalid:* `['a', 'b', null]`

`tags: [String]!`

> This means that the list itself **canot** be null, but it can contain null members.
>
> *valid:* `[], ['a', 'b', null]`
>
> *invalid:* `null`

`tags: [String!]!`

> This means that the list itself **canot** be null, and it cannot contain null members.
>
> *valid:* `[], ['a', 'b']`
>
> *invalid:* `null, [], ['a', 'b', null]`

Comment: I will try out the combinations. But in your first example the valid and invlid items are the same. In the third example, `tags: [String!]!`, empty list, [], is both in valid and invalid list of elements. I am confused.

Comment: I tried the first one - `tags: [String!]`. dynamodb still throws the same error when i send empty list ([]) :(